# Laravel websockets and amazon web service (AWS)

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, websocket

Im trying to deploy my laravel app with [laravel websockets](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets) using an EC2 instance ubuntu server.

But then when i try to serve the artisan using `php artisan websockets:serve`, and im expecting to see some console logs upon connection but i only receive an information of

> Starting the WebSocket server on port 6001...

I tried to debug the data by visiting `example.com/laravel-websockets`. And it only returns

> WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

Im just confused if laravel-websocket can be deployed to amazon web service ec2 instance or is there any configuration to aws need to do to be able to run this laravel-websockets?

**Client side**

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: VUE_APP_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: VUE_APP_PUSHER_HOST,
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
    encrypted:true,
});
```

**config/broadcasting.php**

```
'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'https',
                'curl_options' => [
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                ]
            ],
        ],
```

**Websocket response**

[image: Websocket response]

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: hello, i updated the question and added the codes and response

Comment: Why you had wss and ws pointed to the same port? Can you run both http and https on single port 80? No. Delete your WS port.

Comment: Hello how you solved that problem

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

this is my bootstrap.js configuration:
use window.location.hostname, for ws and wss port.

and plain key.

Also, check whether ec2 instance block 6001 port or not.

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');


window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: '1234567890',
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssHost: window.location.hostname,
    wssPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to see the port is listening or not:

```sh
netstat -tpunl | grep 6001
```

If it is there.
I think EC2 instance server disable external access port 6001.

You need to **open port** 6001 in the **ec2 Security Group**.

Also need to open the same port on the EC2 instance's firewall.